# Register a 4th device for development

Tags: microsoft-account

As a Windows enthusiast developer, I just bought a 4th Windows Phone.
I have (not counting my Windows Surface):

- HTC Mozart (Windows Phone 7.5)
- Nokia 620 (Windows Phone 8.0)
- Nokia 630 (Windows Phone 8.1)
- Nokia 925 (Windows Phone 8.0)

Unfortunately, [Microsoft](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/Account/Devices) tells me I am limited to 3 devices. I didn't know it!

So, which phone should I throw away to trash, the N620 or the N935?

Wait, no, the real question is: is there a way for Microsoft to be nice and allow me to register a 4th device for me to create amazing stuff with beacons, voice control, [mind control](http://store.neurosky.com/products/mindwave-1)...?

Or would someone have a script to unregister/register devices on the fly (one click) so I'm always under the limit of 3 devices?

Or should I get 2 emails, 2 Live accounts, 2 developer accounts, and switch all the time between the two, depending on the connected device?

Comment: Do you mean Lumia 925? I am unaware of a 935.

Comment: Fixed, it was 925 indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft only allows 3 devices. You can swap them out by hand in the dev center, but there is no way to script this.

The key to remember about testing with the different devices you have aren't just OS differences, but hardware capabilities. You have to decide what you are testing for. You can verify many of these differences on the emulator, mainly screen size and memory limitations.

This leaves testing features that the emulator can't handle. Do you need to test how your app handles a device that doesn't have a sensor you require? Do you need to access the speed property from the location object? These are things you need a device for.

Once you decide what you need to test specifically on hardware, you can then choose which devices will best help you.

That said, with the devices you provided. If you are developing something that isn't going to run WP 7.5, lose the Mozart. If you do, drop the 620. It is close enough to the 630 but older.